# R function to standardize address (e.g. if 1-5 Park Ave exists, replace 1 Park Ave or 5 Park Ave with 1-5 Park Ave)

Tags: r, arrays, string, dataframe, dplyr

I am working with address data in R. I have provided an example data frame (feel free to switch to a tibble or data table). I am trying to standardise the addresses, e.g. if an address like 10-12 smith st is in the data, I would like to replace all occurrences of 10 smith street and 12 smith street to 10-12 smith street. Of course, there should be no change to 12 park ave, since this is a different address. The building number is in the 'blg_no' column and the street name is in the 'street' column. An example follows.

```
data = data.frame(matrix(nrow=10,ncol=2))
colnames(data) = c('street','blg_no')
data$street = c('smith st','smith st','smith st','smith st','smith st','park ave','park 
ave','park ave','george lane','george lane')
data$blg_no = c('10','10-12','36','12','13-15','27','12','27-29','34-38','15')

> data
   street blg_no
1   smith     10
2   smith  10-12
3   smith     36
4   smith     12
5   smith  13-15
6    park     27
7    park     12
8    park  27-29
9  george  34-38
10 george     15
```

Expected output is:

```
> data
   street blg_no
1   smith  10-12
2   smith  10-12
3   smith     36
4   smith  10-12
5   smith  13-15
6    park  27-29
7    park     12
8    park  27-29
9  george  34-38
10 george     15
```

This seems doable using list comprehensions on Python, but I can't find a way to do this on R.

Answer (score 0):

```
data$street = as.factor(data$street)
out = data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(data), nrow = 0))
for(c in levels(data$street)){
    temp = data[data$street==c,]
    temp2 = unique(temp$blg_no[grepl('-', temp$blg_no)])
    for(v in temp2){
        temp3 = str_split(v, '-')
        temp$blg_no = ifelse(temp$blg_no == temp3[[1]][1], v, temp$blg_no)
        temp$blg_no = ifelse(temp$blg_no == temp3[[1]][2], v, temp$blg_no)}
    out = rbind(existing,temp)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it, using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse)

Steps:

1. Load the library
2. Pull out the first number, and the last number (if it exists from each row, and save this temporary dataframe as `d`
3. Left join this dataframe with a version of itself with only the rows with ranges, joining on a row in the range df with the same street name, and a range that includes the first number in the row.
4. Create the final `blg_no` column- for rows where no range matches, simply return the value. Otherwise, return the range.

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- mutate(data, e = str_extract(blg_no, "\\d+$") %>% as.integer,
            blg_no = str_extract(blg_no, "\\d+") %>% as.integer)
            
left_join(d,
          d |> filter(blg_no != e),
          join_by(street, between(blg_no, blg_no, e))) |>
  reframe(blg_no = ifelse(is.na(blg_no.y), blg_no.x, paste(blg_no.y, e.y, sep = '-')), .by = street)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   street      blg_no
   <chr>       <chr> 
 1 smith st    10-12 
 2 smith st    10-12 
 3 smith st    36    
 4 smith st    10-12 
 5 smith st    13-15 
 6 park ave    27-29 
 7 park ave    12    
 8 park ave    27-29 
 9 george lane 34-38 
10 george lane 15
```